# Wrong article when clicking on news article with same title

Tags: url, typo3, tt-news

The editor created multiple tt_news article with the same title. If you navigate to the news you can see the correct excerpt, but when clicking on the detail view you get the article which is not the seen in the excerpt. It is an older article with the same title. The URL looks like this

http://yourdomain.com/news/news-detail/duplicate-article-name.html

The following versions are currently used:

- CoolURI 1.0.29
- tt_news 3.0.1
- TYPO3 4.5.10

`CoolUriConf.xml_default` has the following content

```
<uriparts>
    <part>
      <parameter>tx_ttnews[tt_news]</parameter>
      <lookindb>
        <to>SELECT title FROM tt_news WHERE uid=$1</to>
        <t3conv>1</t3conv>
      </lookindb>
    </part>
```

Now I changed it according to the [manual](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/cooluri/1.0.29/view/1/5/) to this

```
  <uriparts>
    <part>
      <parameter>tx_ttnews[tt_news]</parameter>
      <lookindb>
        <to>SELECT CONCAT(tt1.title,IF(tt2.number>1,CONCAT('-',tt2.number),'')) FROM tt_news as tt1, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS number FROM tt_news WHERE title=(SELECT title FROM tt_news WHERE uid=$1)) AS tt2 WHERE tt1.uid=$1</to>
        <t3conv>1</t3conv>
      </lookindb>
    </part>
```

I cleared all caches (including CoolURI cache) but now the latest article can be found if clicking on the URL. The URL hasen't changed.

What I'm doing wrong? I even tried it with another browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the error. It was the wrong file I edited. I edited `typo3conf/ext/cooluri/cooluri/CoolUriConf.xml_default`.

You find the correct path if you go into the `Extension Manager` and click on `CoolURI`. There is a `XML path` variable where the path to your real `CoolUriConf.xml` is. In my case it was `fileadmin`. Now the latest article has the following name:

`http://yourdomain.com/news/news-detail/duplicate-article-name.html`

An older one has this name

`http://yourdomain.com/news/news-detail/duplicate-article-name-2.html`

and so on. There are nicer solutions but all what `CoolURI` can does.

Comment: Can your mark this question as answered/accepted? Thus is will be removed from the list of unanswered questions. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Try to use RealUrl it much much easier than CoolURI to configure.

Ok, I'm thinking about this and try to change query to:

SELECT CONCAT(tt1.title,IF(tt2.number>1,CONCAT('-',tt2.number),'')) FROM tt_news as tt1, (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY uid) AS number FROM tt_news WHERE title=(SELECT title FROM tt_news WHERE uid=$1)) AS tt2 WHERE tt1.uid=$1

After that you should have links like this:

```
http://yourdomain.com/news/news-detail/duplicate-article-name-1.html
http://yourdomain.com/news/news-detail/duplicate-article-name-2.html
http://yourdomain.com/news/news-detail/duplicate-article-name-3.html
```

Comment: The site will be soon upgraded and will get RealUrl. It would be nice if I would have a solution in the meantime.

Comment: Reconfigure site to RealUrl it's 30 minutes of work. Thinking about solution get more time than that :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it managed. I edited the default file instead of the real config file ;) I tried your SQL and got something like `http://yourdomain.com/news/news-detail/265.html`. Most times a take a RealUrl config from another project. Than you are finished within 30 minutes. But changing something like in this case requires more work and I think is as complicated as CoolUri. But that's just my opinion.